# Resize Panes in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-elcapitan, xcode7.1

The resizing of the different Panes/Windows in Xcode often stops working and I have to toggle hide or show in order to reactivate it.

If you look at the images below, sometime I cannot get a resize cursor as shown in the second image.

[image: No Resize]

[image: Yes Resize]

I have been patient. I keep expecting the next version of XCode to solve this bug or maybe the next OSx.

I am now on Xcode 7.1.1 and OSx 10.11.1.

Am I the only one who has the recurrent bug ? Is there a fix anyone knows of ? I always click on one of the toggles switches in the toolbars and it fixes it but I cannot stop it reoccurring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience this has never caused Xcode to freeze, but also you can resize the panes regardless of whether the cursor changes or not. Just point to that area and drag it - it will follow.

Comment: I will retry when it happens again. You misunderstood XCode does not freeze just the resizing does not work, I reworded my question

Comment: I am still evaluating this. Seems you are partly correct, sometimes the drag will still work. I will try some more over the next few days.

Comment: Xcode likes to act weird from time to time. Just get used to it :) Just recently I had to end a class early, because Xcode kept playing a trick on me. Every time I put a UITableViewCell in a xib file, during compilation it would change its type to UITabBarController (without changing anything visually) and this gave me the same run-time error all the time.

Comment: It does indeed seem to resize even without the cursor change